# MySQL triggers alteration

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers, alter-table

Is there any way how to update automatically mysql trigger(s) structure, every time when I alter a table?

Answer (score 1):

No - any alteration that impacts the trigger requires you to update separately from the ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: Thanks.

Is there any tool which can help me to automate it? The problem is, our developers forget all the time to update a trigger structure when they do "alter table".

Comment: @VP: Not that I'm aware of, but I'm out of touch with MySQL tools - sorry.